# drawing on responsive canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

i am trying to create a responsive canvas and i have already done that but, when i am writing something on it then the lines are very blur and not on the same position.there is a gap between the actual x and y coordinate and the line

//resize canvas code

```
 function resize(){    

$("#canvas").outerHeight($(window).height()-$("#canvas").offset().top- 
Math.abs($("#canvas").outerHeight(true) - $("#canvas").outerHeight()));
}
$(document).ready(function(){
resize();
$(window).on("resize", function(){                      
    resize();
});
});
```

how to make the drawing scale perfectly and on the same position of the mouse

Comment: `$("#canvas").height = value;` use this to change your canvas height.

Comment: what is value here

Comment: the value you want to set for canvas height.

Comment: i am done with the canvas size now i want to only ask how to draw perfectly on it

Comment: `$("#canvas").height = ($(window).height()-$("#canvas").offset().top- 
Math.abs($("#canvas").outerHeight(true) - $("#canvas").outerHeight()));` inside your resize function.

Comment: not working still drawing lines and mouse positions are different and they have gap between them and lines are blur